# iOS7 Vs iOS8 auto layout and webview issue

Tags: iphone, ios7, webview, ios8, autolayout

I have a view controller that is composed of a web view and a toolbar with some basic controls. The toolbar is pinned to the bottom of the screen using auto layout. It has four constraints, to pin it to the left side of the screen, the right side of the screen, the bottom of the screen and another that pins the bottom of the web view to the top of the toolbar.

I am having too issues with this. The first is that the web view when loading a URL has a black bar running across the bottom of the screen for a second or two while the page loads, see attached screen shot. This occurs on both iOS7 & iOS8.

[image: black bar while page loads]

[EDIT]
This bug and the one below are related I think. I just discovered that the horizontal indicator when scrolling displays not at the bottom of the screen but higher up, where it would appear if the tabbar where present. 
[/EDIT]

The second issue I am having with iOS7. The screen that calls this screen is the typical navigation bar inside a tab bar setup. The user presses a button to go to a particular page, the browser gets created and pushed onto the navigation bar stack. It hides the tab bar when created. In iOS8 this works perfectly, the toolbar is pinned to the bottom of the screen. In iOS7 the tab bar is removed but the toolbar is placed as if the tab bar was still present?! Any ideas how to fix these two issues? Many thanks.

[image: iOS7 auto layout issue]
[image: iOS8 no auto layout issue]

FYI - Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: in iOS7 it was a known issue moving views up.Generally only for iOS7 add some y value like 20 to the View frame's Y position and decrease the height of the view by 20

Comment: I have the exact same problem and cannot find a fix. Moving or resizing the views is not possible due to autolayout issues.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the problem with iOS 8.

Comment: @Steve sorry I had to jump onto another project. It was fixed by another dev but I do not know what he did to resolve it. I had a quick look through the source code and all I can find is that he sets the tabbar to be hidden in viewWillAppear and the bottom of the webView aligned to the top of the toolbar in the storyboard :/

Comment: @Steve the black bar issue was resolved by setting the opaque property on the webView to be false. But this does not solve the bottom of the webView alignment issue.

Answer (score 0):

The "black bar" is most likely your app window background. At the time of loading the web view is still under the navigation bar. Perhaps the constraints are being overridden. Check your storyboard settings:

[image: xcode settings for views under bars]

If this is it, it might solve the second issue as well.

---

***Speculation***

The reason iOS 8 works is because from Apple talks I gleaned they realise many dev had issues with their views being under the nav bars by default. Introduced with iOS 7. They likely changed this in iOS 8 but found no written evidence. If someone can confirm or deny this, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the delay. I was out of state for a while. I'm afraid my storyboard settings are like you have shown :/ no luck with that.